# Search and replace all characters past the first occurrence of space in each line in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have some text in the following format:

```
column1 DATE,
column2 VARCHAR2(6),
column3 VARCHAR2(15)
```

(It is the format of Oracle column definitions in case you are wondering.)

I’ve been trying to figure out how to replace everything past the space in each line with `VARCHAR2(255),`, but haven’t been successful yet.

I know I can search the occurrences of space via `/\s`, but I can’t figure out how to get the rest of the string on the line. When I use `/\s*`, it highlights all the text. I attempted to use `/\s.+`, but I get a “Pattern not found” error.

How can I get all text past the space in each line and replace it globally with another string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way:

`:%s/ .*/ VARCHAR(255)`

VIM uses a slightly weird regex syntax so if you wanted to do \s+ you'd have to use \s\+

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
:%s/\s\S\+$/ VARCHAR(255)/
```

Comment: Why didn't you use `qq0f C VARCHAR(255)q`, then `:%norm!@q`?  [Aren't substitution one-liners tedious to think?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903660/vi-how-to-generate-a-number-sequence#comment12636451_9903819) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, of course it is a viable solution which you should have added as an answer. I will upvote on it if you post it as one, which is more than I got for my valid solution ^^

Comment: It happens sometimes.  I think, this commands deserves at least one up vote.  +1

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
:%s/\(\s\+\).*$/\1VARCHAR(255)/
```

For every line (`%`), find the first run of whitespace characters (`\(\s\+\)`), save them in match group 1 (to be referenced as `\1` in the replacement string), match the rest of the line (`.*$`), and replace it with the desired literal string.

(You must escape the `+` character in the regexp in *magic mode*. You can use the *very magic* mode with `\v` at the beginning of the regexp. See `:help magic` for details.)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using substitution commands (which have already
been proposed in other answers), one can repeat a sequence of
Normal-mode commands on every line using the `:normal` Ex command:

```
:%norm!f C VARCHAR(255)
```