# Vim: Adding automatic alphabetic and/or numeric index to current file name?

Tags: vim, numbers, sequence

I want to implement a loose version of [Niklas Luhmann's
Zettelkasten](http://takingnotenow.blogspot.com/2007/12/luhmanns-zettelkasten.html)
in Vim. At the core of his method are note snippets that Continue the current
note or Brahch off from it, introducing a slightly different topic or
concept. In the note name, letters indicate branches and numerals
indicate continuations. Like so:

```
note100
note101
    note101a        # branches off from note100 (related topic)
    note101b        # also branches off from note100 (related topic)
        note101b01  # continues note101b (same topic)
        note101b02  # also continues note101b (same topic)
    note101c
note102
```

To implement this in Vim, I need new file
names that are automatically enumerated either as a "continuation" or
a "branch" of the note in current buffer. As a non-coder making first "real" steps in Vimscript, this is where I'm at with the Branching Note function:

```
function! ZettelkastenNewBranchingNote()
    let b:current_note_name = expand('%:t:r')
    let b:new_branching_note = call(BranchingFunctionThatReturnsNewNoteName)
    silent execute 'edit' b:new_branching_note
    echomsg 'New branching note ' b:new_branching_note 'created.'
endfunction
```

The `BranchingFunctionThatReturnsNewNoteName()` should take
`b:current_note_name` and extend it with automatic alphabetical(!)
index (counting alphabetically upwards). How could I accomplish this?

Also, for my New Continued Note function: how could I numerically
count upwards from the *last numeric part* of the current file name? (E.g. `100a01 > 100a02`.)

Thanks for any advice!

(Somewhat relatedly, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903660/vi-how-to-generate-a-number-sequence)
the Nexus plugin is suggested, but I'd prefer to keep my script
self-contained.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide a great deal of context (which is great), but are light on the needed algorithm. To me, it looks like this: If the current file ends with a letter, increase it, else (it's a number), append an `a` to start the alphabetical sequence.

Checks are done in Vim with *regular expressions*; `\a` is a short form for `[A-Za-z]` (you could also write `[[:alpha:]]`; yes it's that flexible), and `$` *anchors* it to the end of the name:

```
if b:current_note_name =~ '\a$'
    ...
```

Extract the last character with `matchstr()`.

```
    let lastAlpha = matchstr(b:current_note_name, '\a$')
    if lastAlpha ==? 'z'
        " TODO: Handle overflow
    endif
```

To "increase" an alphabetical character, convert it first to a number, increase, then back:

```
    let newAlpha = nr2char(char2nr(lastAlpha) + 1)
```

To replace, you use `substitute()`, again with the same regexp.

```
    let b:new_branching_note = substitute(b:current_note_name, '\a$', newAlpha, '')
```

Appending is simple:

```
else
    let b:new_branching_note = b:current_note_name . 'a'
endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the explanations; these are very helpful in my learning process. (I particularly like the nr2char builtin - very nice!) This solution does correctly create the file but I also get "E121: Undefined variable: b:new_branching_note". Why?

Comment: The variable isn't defined yet (in that buffer). You may need a check somewhere: `if ! exists('b:new_branching_note`) ...`

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved with `let b:current_note_name = exists('b:current_note_name') ? b:current_note_name : expand('%:t:r')`. I also had to modify some variable types from `b:` to `s:`.