# Vim - incremental numbering via regular expression search and replace

Tags: regex, vim, emacs, increment, substitution

I have this code:

```
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Murka", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-10-31", "breed_id" => 1),
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Jurka", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-11-31", "breed_id" => 2),
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Nyash", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-12-31", "breed_id" => 3),
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Meowy", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-01-31", "breed_id" => 4),
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Yummi", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-10-31", "breed_id" => 2),
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Barss", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-05-31", "breed_id" => 2),
array ('id' => 1, 'name' => "Nonam", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-05-31", "breed_id" => null
```

I'll want to change all `'id' => 1` (except the 1st) so the number will increment by 1. It's simple to achieve with Emacs:

```
M-x replace-regexp
\(1,\)
\,(1+ \#),
```

As described [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplaceRegexp#toc2). After some research the maximum that I've been able to achieve with Vim is (inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903660/vi-how-to-generate-a-number-sequence)):

```
:let i=1 | g/1,/ s//\=i/ | let i+=1
```

But this removes all the following commas:

```
array ('id' => 1 'name' => "Murka", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-10-31", "breed_id" => 1),
array ('id' => 2 'name' => "Jurka", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-11-31", "breed_id" => 2),
array ('id' => 3 'name' => "Nyash", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-12-31", "breed_id" => 3),
array ('id' => 4 'name' => "Meowy", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-01-31", "breed_id" => 4),
array ('id' => 5 'name' => "Yummi", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-10-31", "breed_id" => 2),
array ('id' => 6 'name' => "Barss", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-05-31", "breed_id" => 2),
array ('id' => 7 'name' => "Nonam", 'date_of_birth' => "2014-05-31", "breed_id" => null),
```

So I have to fix it (I know it's easy).

I am aware of [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Generating_a_column_of_increasing_numbers) and macros, I'm just interested to know if there any one-line command solution in Vim.

More general question: is it possible in Vim to inject some logic like conditional statements, manipulating on regex back references? The example for this in Emacs would be:

```
C-M-% \(^.*\)\(linear-gradient(\)\(to right\|to bottom\)\(.*$\) <RET>
\& C-q C-j
\1-prefix-\2\,(if (equal "to right" \3) "left" "top")\4
```

This one helped me about a year+ ago to refactor some huge scary HTML code that had a much of inline CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an answer to your general question, but I do have one for your specific situation.  You can make your command work by putting the comma into a positive look-ahead, like this:

```
:let i=1 | g/1(\,\)\@=/ s//\=i/ | let i+=1
```

Now it will only replace the `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Adding this to my favorites :)

Comment: You can simplify your regex by using `\ze` instead of a positive lookahead. e.g. `:let i=1 | g/1\ze,/ s//\=i/ | let i+=1`

Comment: :let i=1 | g/1\ze,/ s//\=i/ | let i+=1 is really use full for me. Please let me know is it possible to select the range of lines. Means I need to replace only lines from 10 to 20 in the file. How we can specify that:

Answer (score 3):

A really easy solution:

```
:%norm f1s^R=line('.')^M
```

Obtained like this:

```
:%norm f1s<C-v><C-r>=line('.')<C-v><CR>
```

If you are not comfortable with typing complete macros on the command-line you can achieve the same result via recording:

```
qq
f1s<C-r>=line('.')<CR>
q
[range]@q
```

Comment: This way is a bit esoteric for me, but it works, and I'll definitely give it a try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. go to the second line, put the cursor over the first 1, now start a visual block selection <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>, press `j` until the line you want increment and press  <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>