# Yank and paste but with small change

Tags: vim

I want to put a specified number after each pasted line automatically and this number will increment every past.

Sometimes I want to declare many variables. So I write one declaration and copy(yank) it and past to a second line. Then I can repeat this operation with dot operator ".". But it's very annoying to make these variables vary.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
variable (yy)     variable1 (yy)
variable (p)      variable2 (p)
variable (.)  =>  variable3 (.)
variable (.)      variable4 (.)
variable (.)      variable5 (.)
```

Is it possible to perform such a operation in just the vim?

Comment: Use macros, Luke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903660/vi-how-to-generate-a-number-sequence

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if someone can do it with ultisnips interpolation, I think it is possible but I came up with this solution

```
yy4p .......... copy 4 times
v} ............ select block
g<Ctrl-a> ..... increase the sequence
```

Until here you have the main solution that is increasing the numbers fast

```
fy ............ jump to the first 'y'
<Ctrl-v> ...... start selection block
3jl ........... extend selection
c.<Esc> ....... swich 'yy' with .
fy. ........... finishes
```

Using macro

```
qa ............ start recording marcro 'a'
yyp ........... copy line
ci(.<Esc> ..... change first ()
Ctrl-a ........ increase
ci(. .......... change second ()
Esc ........... stop recording macro 'a'
3@a ........... 4x macro 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/variable/\= printf("variable%d",line('.')-6)/
```

or if you have a vim with perl support (default in many linux distributions)

```
:perldo s/variable/$& . ++$n/e
```

Answer (score 0):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) has `gpp` and `gPp` mappings for this (and many more paste variations). The first only increments the first decimal number, the second one all numbers.

So, starting with

```
variable1 = 'foo1'
```

`yygpp` will create:

```
variable1 = 'foo1'
variable2 = 'foo1'
```

whereas `yygPp` will do this:

```
variable1 = 'foo1'
variable2 = 'foo2'
```

These support a `[count]` and can be repeated with `.`, too.