# Vim : How to actually insert line numbers in the file?

Tags: vim, line-numbers

I know about displaying line numbers in Vim using `:set nu` but what I really want is to make those line numbers the actual contents of the file , preferably only some part of the file.  fancy and works outside vim `cat -n fileName >> fileName.numbers`  . Any suggestions to make it work inside Vim?

Comment: `:%!awk '{print NR,$0}' %`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add line numbers in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/add-line-numbers-in-vim)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the file through a program that numbers the lines, for example `cat`:

```
:%!cat -n
```

To number only some lines, first select the lines in visual mode (command <kbd>V</kbd>) and then type <kbd>:</kbd>. The prompt changes into `:'<,'>` and you can type the rest of command `!cat -n`. The full command is:

```
:'<,'>!cat -n
```

Comment: any suggestions for just numbering selected lines in visual mode ?

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out the increment package [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/increment.vim--Avadhanula).  If you have a block of text,

```
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

You can select the 't' on the first line, and enter visual block mode using `Ctrl-V`.  Select until the last line, then enter insert mode with `I`.  Enter the number '1' plus a space, and hit escape to leave visual block mode.  You'll then have a 1 before each line:

```
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
1 test
```

Next, highlight all of the 1's in visual block mode again, and type `:Inc<CR>`.  This will increment the numbers, essentially numbering your lines in text:

```
 1 test
 2 test
 3 test
 4 test
 5 test
 6 test
 7 test
 8 test
 9 test
10 test
11 test
```