# Add index column to CSV file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a large Comma-Separated File (6GB) and would like to add an index column to it. I'm looking at Unix type solutions for efficiency. I'm using a Mac.

I have this:

```
V1  V2  V3
0.4625  0.9179  0.8384
0.9324  0.2486  0.1114 
0.6691  0.7813  0.6705
0.1935  0.3303  0.4336
```

Would like to get this:

```
ID  V1  V2  V3
1   0.4625  0.9179  0.8384
2   0.9324  0.2486  0.1114
3   0.6691  0.7813  0.6705
4   0.1935  0.3303  0.4336
```

Comment: Is the format fixed-width or tab separated?

Comment: Some platform information would be useful here. Answers so far have assumed a Unix-like platform. But maybe the OP is on Windows. Do you have a particular tool in mind?

Comment: @ Tom Fenech - It's comma separated

Comment: @LondonRob - I'm using a Mac. I kept the question vague because I know very little about Unix.

Comment: @SharkSandwich, if it's comma separated then you should have shown that in your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will probably work:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  NR == 1 {print "ID", $0; next}
  {print (NR-1), $0}
' input.csv > output.csv
```

In `awk`, the `NR` variable is "the total number of input records seen so far", which in general means "the current line number".  So the `NR == 1` in the first line is how we match the first record and add the "ID" column header, and for the remaining lines we use `NR-1` as the index.

The `-F'\t'` argument sets the input field separator, and `-vOFS='\t'` sets the *output* field separator.

Comment: Looks good, although personally I would remove the `-F` as the default will do.

Comment: any way to make it faster? or ideally to use multiple cores?

Comment: @AbdulMoiz I'm not sure what you're talking about. If you run this script against the sample input data, it produces exactly the required output. The output is a perfectly standard tab-separated file, which is what was requested by the OP.

Comment: @larsks Sorry my bad

Answer (score 5):

Since no technology is specified in the original post, I'd be happy here to keep it simple.

*(all the fancy `Vim`/`bash` solutions are fine if you know what you're doing)*.

- Open the CSV file in your favourite spreadsheet programme (I'm using
  LibreOffice, but Excel or a native Mac equivalent will do)
- insert a column to the left of column A
- Enter a 1 into cell A2, the first cell under the headers
- Double-click the blob at the bottom right of the cell as shown in the screenshot:

[image: LibreOffice wizardry]

This last step will fill the index column with `1,2,3...` etc.
You can then save the resulting spreadsheet as a CSV file again.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can't use a spreadsheet program due to the size of the file. It is approximately 6GB. That was why I was looking at Unix type solutions.

Comment: Why don't you add to the original post all the detail which you've added in the various comments to various answers? It'll save more people trying to guess what your situation is.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a commas delimited file.

Using vim, open the file. In normal mode, type

```
:%s/^/\=line('.').','/
```

`:%s/^/\=line('.')/` adds the line number at the beginning of the line. Since you have a commas delimited file (add a column) you need a comma after your line number. so the `.','`

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253041/14673) for full explanation about `:%s/^/\=line('.')/`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the CSV file in your favorite spreadsheet program, such as Excel
2. Insert a column to the left side of first column
3. Type 1 in the first cell of this column
4. Type an equation '*=A2+1*' in the following cell

[image]

5. Double-click the blob at the bottom right of the cell as shown in the screenshot

[image]