# How to insert line number followed by a space in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I know the command `:%s/^/\=line('.')/` will insert line number at the start of each line as below.

Before

```
line1
line2
line3
```

After

```
1line1
2line2
3line3
```

But I want to insert a <kbd>space</kbd> after the line number as below.

```
1 line1
2 line2
3 line3
```

I tried giving a <kbd>space</kbd> after `line('.')` in the command, but doesn't work.

`:%s/^/\=line('.') /`

### Edit: The question and the answers provided here are different from those of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/add-line-numbers-to-source-code-in-vim).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can correct your try like this: `:%s/^/\=line('.').' '/`

The problem was that it was parsing your space as part of the expression `line('.')`. But as you are inside an expression, you can use the `.` (dot) operator to concatenate strings.

Comment: Is there a way to line up things as well as the answer from ronalch does?

Comment: @SJain : not easily; ronalchn's solution is really better for this.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
%s/^/\=printf('%d ', line('.'))
```

This also means you can pad out the integer so that things line up:

```
%s/^/\=printf('%4d ', line('.'))
```

or to put a dot or colon:

```
%s/^/\=printf('%4d. ', line('.'))
```