# How to remove line numbers in vim?

Tags: bash, vim, terminal

I have set line numbers in vim using `:%!cat -n` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/add-line-numbers-to-source-code-in-vim/252774?noredirect=1#comment60758218_252774).
The line numbers appeard but now when I open vim I am getting 'E481: No range allowed:' errors and now I want to get rid of the line numbers. But how?

Comment: Are you looking for `help rnu`? instead od trying `:%!cat -n`

Comment: I am looking for a solution which can make the line number dissapear. I am a begginer with vim (1 and half years).

Comment: You added line numbers to you .vimrc file and then saved it? So they are actually **in** the file on disk? And now you want to remove them from there again?

Comment: I have not modified the .vimrc file. I've just issued the `:%!cat -n` command directly from vim. So basicly if you open vim and issue the `:%!cat -n` command the line numbers will appear, but how to remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can try this to get the line numbers:

```
:%!cat -n %
```

If you've not saved, you can revert back to the last save:

```
:e!
```

If you have the line numbers, then you can get rid of them like this

```
:%s/^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]*\t//
```