# Vim - add line numbers to selection starting from 1

Tags: vim

I am using following code (from somewhere on the net but I forgot the page) to add line numbers to text files:

```
:%s/^/\=printf('%d] ' , line('.'))/g
```

I have tried to modify it to accept ranges:

```
command -range=% Addln <line1>,<line2>s/^/\=printf('%d] ' , line('.'))/g
```

It works for whole file all right, but when I try to apply it to a selection, it adds line numbers starting from file line number and not 1. How can I change it so that it adds line numbers to the selection starting from 1? Thanks.

Comment: Without the command, use `line("'<")`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/add-line-numbers-to-source-code-in-vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `<line1>` identifier will be replaced by Vim with the actual first line number of the command's range, you can use that to do arithmetic with it: Just subtract it from the current `line('.')` and add one for a 1-based numbering:

```
command -range=% Addln <line1>,<line2>s/^/\=printf('%d] ' , line('.') - <line1> + 1)/g
```