# Vim- combine 2 commands using ranges to one

Tags: vim

I have 2 commands that work all right to add line numbers to whole file or selection and to change those line numbers to create `1]` format:

```
command -range=% Addln2 <line1>,<line2>!cat -n 
command -range=% Addln3 <line1>,<line2>s/\v\s+(\d+)\s+/\1] /g
```

However, I am not able to combine them to one command. I tried:

```
command -range=% Addln2 <line1>,<line2>!cat -n | s/\v\s+(\d+)\s+/\1] /g
```

but it produces error.

Using sed also does not work:

```
command -range=% Addln2 <line1>,<line2>!cat -n | sed 's/\v\s+(\d+)\s+/\1] /g'
```

I also tried to put them together in a function:

```
function Addlnfn() range
    a:firstline,a:lastline !cat -n 
    a:lastline,a:firstline s/\v\s+(\d+)\s+/\1] /g
endfunction

command -range=% Addlnfn <line1>,<line2>call Addlnfn()
```

But this also produces an error: `Missing endfunction`

Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like this instead and don't have to rely on external programs `3,10s/^/\=line(".")-2."] "`

Comment: How can I convert this to a command that works on whole file as well as on visual selection.

Comment: This should do it `function! Test() range
  execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^/\=line(".")-' . a:firstline . '."] "'
endfunction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `|` can be used to separate commands, but there are exceptions, and `:!` is one of them, as `:help :bar` explains. The reason here is that the external shell command invoked by `:!` may be a *pipeline* (e.g. `cmd1 | grep foo`), so the `|` character needs to be part of the arguments, and cannot separate Vim commands.

One workaround is to surround the first command with `:execute`:

```
command -range=% Addln2 execute '<line1>,<line2>!cat -n' | s/\v\s+(\d+)\s+/\1] /g
```

---

Moving the commands into a function is another good approach. What you've missed is that the evaluation of the `a:firstline,a:lastline` function arguments doesn't happen automatically in Vimscript. Again `:execute` comes to the rescue:

```
function Addlnfn() range
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!cat -n'
    execute a:lastline . ',' . a:firstline . 's/\v\s+(\d+)\s+/\1] /g'
endfunction
command -range=% Addlnfn <line1>,<line2>call Addlnfn()
```

#### Overall critique

You don't need an external command to number the lines; this can be done purely inside Vim. Looking at your [other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253267/vim-add-line-numbers-to-selection-starting-from-1/44256391), it seems you've already discovered that.